# get text input from wpf window

Tags: wpf, keyboard, window

I'm using a key_up event on my window to append the data typed to a string builder.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdMain" KeyUp="grdMain_KeyUp">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>...

    private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
        {
            buffer.Append(e.Key);
        }
```

the thing is that the data applied to the buffer is "NumPad4" instead of "4" and "D3" instead of "3"...
am i missing something? is there a way to append the data as if it was typed into a textbox?
i know that i can convert the data my self but it seems weird that there is no built in way to do so.

Comment: well it is not weird that layout container has no TextChanged event - it doesn't have text. The weird thing is the one you are doing. Why do you need the Grid to receive text?

Comment: actually it's a customer request. he doesn't want to concern about where the focus is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this may seem weird at first glance, but I believe that it's the right way to do that. I derived from a `TextBox` and added `ContentPresenter` there to host any content and the `Content` property to set that content.

So, create WPF Custom Control (it's Visual Studio template) called TextBoxContainer. add the following property to it:

```
    #region Content (DependencyProperty)

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Content property
    /// </summary>
    public object Content
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(TextBoxContainer),
          new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion
```

Replace it's style in Assets/generic.xaml file with the following:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxContainer}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxContainer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use it like following:

```
<local:TextBoxContainer TextChanged="TextBoxGrid_TextChanged" >
    <local:TextBoxContainer.Content>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Any markup here -->
        </Grid>
    </local:TextBoxContainer.Content>
</local:TextBoxContainer>
```

Note that at any time it has text that contains all text that was input. The only thing that you should be aware of is that some elements prevent some events from bubbling up. For example `TextBox` stops `KeyDown` event bubbling. So if you place `TextBox` inside `TextBoxContainer` and user will click on it and start to input text there - TextBoxContainer will not receive that text, although it will fire `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TextCompositionManager.TextInput Attached Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositionmanager.textinput.aspx).

```
<Grid x:Name="grdMain"
      TextCompositionManager.TextInput="grid_TextInput">
```

In [TextCompositionEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.aspx) you will find what you want.

```
private void grid_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Text);
}
```